# echo a variable, but not displaying result

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT: ups that's embarrassing... I forgot to connect to the database. Sorry for the inconvenience :(**

I'd like to echo the value of the variable $number_row, but nothing is displayed

```
<?php 
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos"); // this counts how many videos are
$number_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultado);
echo "$number_rows";
?>
```

Comment: what is the value of var_dump($number_rows);

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error()` -- most likely there's a database connection error or something similar.

Comment: FYI, `var_dump(mysql_error())` would've given you something like the following: `Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` (the PHP user on localhost, with no password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have written. The problem must lie elsewhere. Have you connected successfully to mysql?

Although deprecated and therefore this should not be used like it is have you got something like thid in your code?

```
mysql_connect('localhost','name','pwd');
mysql_select_db('db');
```

Comment: is this your answer for his problem? if you want to comment there is a comment section below question

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP and not an answer. Please read the guidelines. In general, if you make a question or a statement like this, something is obviously wrong in the OP, and hence you should give him the chance to correct it. **Edit**: With the `mysql_connect` function calls your question makes more sense - disregard the comment.

Comment: @PankajKhairnar after checking out the code on my server and seeing it work for me, this is my answer.

Comment: ups that's embarrassing... I forgot to connect to the database. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: @InGodITrust and everybody here know there is not problem with this code. but before giving answer you should know what is the exact problem

Comment: @Tresk thought so, glad it helped,  dont forget to accept the answer when you can!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$resultado = mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_of_videos 
    FROM videos
"); // this counts how many videos are
if ($resultado) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
    echo $row["num_of_videos"];
}
```